# Tabs for Media:youtube multiple videos of single node

Tags: media, files

I am using Media:youtube in a content type and the field in which I embed youtube videos might have multiple values.
I am trying to put those multiple youtube videos belonging to a node in tabs dynamically.

Eg: I have a node created with title: example of tabs
underneath that I have embedded two youtube videos in the node
output should be in tabs with part1 as first horizontal tab and part-2 as second horizontal tab.
Part1|part2

with part1 loaded first and i should click part2 for second video

When there are 3 videos loaded in a node, then I should have like part1|part2|part3

I think using Display Suite with a add code field which i think should have a forloop with delta values of video will solve the purpose.I have no php coding knowledge

Can someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use could use the [Field Collection Tab formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs) module with [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)?

Here are some more details about these modules (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [Field Collection Tab formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs):

> ... provides a field formatter that allows you to output a multi value field collection field as a tabset, with one tab per field collection item.

- [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection):

> ... Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached. A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.